# Javascript for group of text boxes with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a group of text boxes with class as 'track'. All text boxes are in separate td. I have particular div for each text boxes that is bind in same td. I am trying to write a JavaScript function for each text boxes (Auto complete function) such that it gives me suggestion in that particular div.

I have structure is...

```
<tr>
    <td><input name="track[]" type="text" class="track" maxlength="150" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();"/>
      <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;"><img src="images/upArrow.png" style="position: relative; top: -12px; left: 50px;" alt="upArrow" />
        <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList">&nbsp;</div>
      </div></td>
</tr>
```

Is it easy to write JavaScript function or jquery for this?

```
function lookup(track) {    
    if(track.length == 0) {
        // Hide the suggestion box.
        $('#suggestions').hide();
    } else {
        //alert("Hiiii");
        $.post("rpc.php", {queryString: ""+track+""}, function(data){
            if(data.length >0) {
                $('#suggestions').show();
                $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
}

function fill(thisValue) {
    $('#track').val(thisValue);
    setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 500);
}
```

**Note** How can I convert it for each text box. That it give suggestion for that particular text box and fill only that particular text box.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following will do what you're looking for. I made a slight change to `lookup()` -- it now requires that you pass in the input element in question as well. That's what allows it to make the necessary changes to the right suggestion elements.

```
function lookup(poetname, inputElement) {
    var suggestions = inputElement.next();
    if(poetname.length == 0) {
        // Hide the suggestion box.
        suggestions.hide();
    } else {
        //alert("Hiiii");
        $.post("rpc.php", {queryString: ""+poetname+""}, function(data){
            if(data.length >0) {
                suggestions.show();
                suggestions.children('div').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
}

$('input.track').keyup(function(){
    lookup($(this).val(), $(this));
});
```

Comment: DO I need to change to HTML also? I mean to say I have skipped `onblur` event in HTML input box. DO I need to change `onkeyup` event or what parameter I need to pass as second parameter in `lookup` function. Because still yet I am getting error as inputElement is not defined.

Comment: `next().next()` isn't any Element it's `null` The `.suggestionList` is a child of `.suggestionsBox`

Comment: @AndreasAL - thanks, I've fixed it. OP -- in the future please format your html more clearly. Regarding your question, in general inline JS is considered bad practice. If you want `lookup()` to run on a blur event, then just change `keyup` to `blur` in my code. As far as the second parameter you need to pass to `lookup()`, just look at my code. The first parameter is the input's value, the second one is the input element itself.

Comment: @maxedison: I am still not clear with your answer. Means should I remove on blur or onkeyup event from my html. Because if I use this on HTML code it gives me error inputelement is not defined.

Comment: Yes, remove the inline JS from your HTML. And make sure you wrap the `$('input.track').keyup...` code inside `$(document).ready(function(){...});`

Answer (score 0):

Put an ID on the input inside the TD and pass that in to lookup function as well. You can then show and hide the nearest div with a particular class using jquery as you wish with that ID.

Answer (score 0):

Its very bad to have more than one element with the same ID. I have removed all your id attributes from your code.

look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FXfLn/3/

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input name="track[]" type="text" class="track" maxlength="150"/>
            <div class="suggestionsBox" style="display: none;">
                <div class="suggestionList">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input name="track[]" type="text" class="track" maxlength="150"/>
            <div class="suggestionsBox" style="display: none;">
                <div class="suggestionList">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

....

```
var lookup = function() { 
    var poetname = this.value;
    var $list = $(this).siblings(".suggestionsBox");
    if(poetname.length == 0) {
        $list.hide();
    } else {

        //Just for testing:

        $list.show();
        $list.find(".suggestionList").html(Math.random());

        // Do your ajax call.

        //$.post("rpc.php", {queryString: poetname}, function(data){
        //    if(data.length >0) {
        //        $list.show();
        //        $list.find(".suggestionList").html(data);
        //    }
        //});
    }
}

var fill = function() {
    var thisValue = this.value;
    $('#poetname').val(thisValue);
    var $list = $(this).siblings(".suggestionsBox");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $list.hide();
    }, 500);
}

$(".track").bind("keyup", lookup);
$(".track").bind("blur", fill);
```

Comment: Is jquery naming convention allowed us to take variable name starting with `$` as u have taken `$list`?

Comment: Not to worry jQuery only reserves the variable $ not $abc. It's the same as: `var a = "something"; var ab = "something else"` . Is it illegal to make the `ab` variable? .. If you want to add a function or variable to the jQuery namespace do: `$.abc` this is something else. see the `.` SHORT: `$` is just a normal character like `a, b, c`. But alone it represent jQuery. Other frameworks also use the short `$` like prototype.

Comment: I normally use the `$something` to mind myself about I'm working with a jQuery Object. :)

Answer (score 0):

Attach the keyup for each text box and use the AJAX call's return on the div's that are children of the same parent td as follows:

```
$('input.track').keyup(function() {
    var poetname = $(this).val();
    if(poetname.length == 0) {
        // Hide the suggestion box.
        $(this).parent().find('#suggestions').hide();
    } 
    else {
        $.ajax({
            url: "rpc.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {queryString: poetname},
            context: this, // i.e. the text box
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.length >0) {
                    $(this).parent().find('#suggestions').show();
                    $(this).parent().find('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

You'd also want to do this on blur:

```
$('input.track').blur(function() {
    $(this).val('');
    $(this).parent().find('#suggestions').hide();
});
```

Now for filling the text-box when a suggestion is clicked. That depends on how each suggestion is listed inside the autoSuggestions div. Assuming that suggestions come from rpc.php in the form:

```
<div class="suggestion_item">suggestion text here</div>
<div class="suggestion_item">suggestion text here</div>
...
```

You can do something like:

```
$('.suggestion_item').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('td').find('.track').val($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: @vijaykrishnan K: Nice vijay I have like your answer but you have not mentioned how will it fill my textbox if I click any of the suggestion.

Comment: That depends on how each suggestion is listed inside the autoSuggestions div. Assuming each suggestion is stored as 
`<div class="suggestion_item">suggestion text here</div>`, 
You can do something like:
`$('.suggestion_item').click(function() {
  $(this).parents('td').find('.track').val($(this).text());
});`